# Xamarin Forms Flyout Menu Not Showing

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, flyout

This is my first time I try to implement the flyouts menu in Xamarin forms. I created first a blank page and followed the documentation but for some reason the menu is not showing. The tabbar in case you are wondering will be added dynamically that is why it is empty. What might be the problem? Thanks in advance.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Bufib.Tools"
            xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Bufib.Views.FlyoutPages"
            x:Class="Bufib.MainPage">

    <Shell.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem x:Name="audioOptn" IconImageSource="{local:ImageResource Bufib.Logos.audio.png}" />
    </Shell.ToolbarItems>
    
    <!-- NAVIGATION -->
    <Shell.FlyoutHeader>
        <StackLayout Padding="10">
            <Label x:Name="flyoutHeaderLbl" Text="Bufib" FontSize="Header" />
        </StackLayout>
    </Shell.FlyoutHeader>
    
    <FlyoutItem x:Name="syllabusPage" >
        <Tab>
            <ShellContent Route="SyllabusPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:SyllabusPage}" /> 
        </Tab>
    </FlyoutItem>
    
    <FlyoutItem x:Name="historyPage">
        <Tab>
            <ShellContent Route="HistoryPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:HistoryPage}" />
        </Tab>
    </FlyoutItem>
    
    <FlyoutItem x:Name="managePage">
        <Tab>
            <ShellContent Route="ManagePage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:ManagePage}" />
        </Tab>
    </FlyoutItem>
    
    <FlyoutItem x:Name="errorPage">
        <Tab>
            <ShellContent Route="ErrorPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:ErrorPage}" />
        </Tab>
    </FlyoutItem>
    
    <FlyoutItem x:Name="aboutPage">
        <Tab>
            <ShellContent Route="AboutPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:AboutPage}" />
        </Tab>
    </FlyoutItem>
    
    <FlyoutItem x:Name="callUsPage">
        <Tab>
            <ShellContent Route="CallUsPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:CallUsPage}" />
        </Tab>
    </FlyoutItem>
    <!-- END NAVIGATION TABS -->
    
    <!--- TABS -->
    <TabBar x:Name="tabBar"></TabBar>
    <!--- END TABS -->
</Shell>
```

Comment: you don't have Title or Icon properties defined for any of your FlyoutItem

Comment: @Jason they were set programatically

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that it was a navigation page. I navigated to it using **MainPage = new Navigation(new MainPage())** which causes the problem. So the solution was changing it to **MainPage = new MainPage()**